# jQuery - Wait till background images have loaded then show element

Tags: jquery, background, load, wait

I did find a few places where it was told how to do this but it was either super inconvenient or just didnt work.. ( the guys own example did not work.. )

Basically i have background images that i would like to show at the same time instead of letting them to load in to the document when ever they please...

I dont necessarily need them to be loaded first or anything **but to wait until specific background images load up and then show their parent div..**

Also if its possible.. it would make big difference if those background images could be defined to be loaded through classes rather than specifying the actual image name... like

.load-bg ~ background load ~ show element..

Am i reaching for the moon or is this doable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My plugin, [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages), allows you to attach callbacks when images have loaded.

It supports images referenced in the CSS.

```
$('#some-container').waitForImages({
    waitForAll: true,
    finished: function() {
        // Loaded all images referenced in CSS.
    }
});
```

Comment: @prismspecs It won't automatically fire the callback if the background image changes. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an asynchronous image loader with a callback to an event which shows the divs holding the images.  Here are some async loaders:

- [JAIL (jQuery Asynchronous Image Loader)](http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail)
- [Image Loader JQuery Plugin](http://www.staticvoid.info/imageLoader/)

  - Note: See the `allcomplete` event on that page.

Also, an SO q/a that might be helpful: [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery/4765156#4765156)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the '[ImagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)' Plugin works for me.

Use like so:

```
// jQuery
$('#container').imagesLoaded( { background: true }, function() {
  console.log('#container background image loaded');
});

// vanilla JS
imagesLoaded( '#container', { background: true }, function() {
  console.log('#container background image loaded');
});
```